# When opening Community Builder it errors "$P.app.postmessage is not a constructor", then "$P.auraRun is not a function"

Tags: community, lightning-community, digital-experience

My Community has been working fine for years.  This evening I tried to go into Builder and receive the following messages.

When opening Community Builder it errors "$P.app.postmessage is not a constructor", then "$P.auraRun is not a function"

I was able to make basic Builder changes earlier today.  It is as if something changed this evening.  This is a big problem as I need to make Community updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to access the Community Builder about 10 minutes later & everything worked.  Perhaps an update was taking place during the time I had the problem (around 11:55 pm EST).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue following a sandbox refresh. I'm not sure how long it took for the issue to be resolved, but it's now working 5 hours later. It wasn't working for more than an hour.